# How to attach Excel file on send email in Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am using Angular.js to create an Excel file but now I include also that file in my email from how to that possible. My js code:

```
$scope.email = function () {
            var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('exportable').innerHTML], {
                type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;"

            });
            var i = (new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10)) + "_" + "Report.xls";
            saveAs(blob, i);
        };
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="container ">
<div class="row-fluid">

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="control-label" for="Email_Id">Email Id</label>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 spacer10">
        <input class="form-control" id="EmailId" name="EmailId" placeholder="Email-Id" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="control-label" for="Subject">Subject</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 spacer10">
        <input class="form-control" id="Subject" name="Subject" placeholder="Subject.." type="text"
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="control-label" for="Subject">Subject</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 spacer10">

        <input class="form-control" id="Subject" name="Subject" type="file" valu="email()">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="control-label" for="Message">Message</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <textarea class="form-control" cols="20" id="Message" name="Message" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

on this code type file, auto includes Excel file on creating time.

Comment: I do not know actually this will work. You have to add vbscript in excel and send email through it,. http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/send-emails-excel-vba/

Comment: it work on excel file download time or i do not know about vb our company work on php

Comment: Then you have to write sending email code on server and make ajax call on it. If you want to excel data than you have to upload excel to server also or send data through ajax call

Comment: If you need to send email from Javascript take a look at [EmailJS](http://www.emailjs.com) - it support file attachments as well (disclosure: I'm one of the founders).